# return concat two slices in go

Tags: arrays, slice

I'm trying to write a function that concate two slices. But whatever I try it returns something like

[1] empty [2] empty [3] empty [4] slice[1] …

I don't want there to be empty indexes.

```
package main

import "fmt"


func main() {
    var input string
    var list1  []string
    var list2  []string

    list1 = make([]string, 3)
    list2 = make([]string, 3)

    fmt.Println("Tell me three friends you like.")

    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        fmt.Print("friend: ")
        fmt.Scanf("%s", &input)
        list1 = append(list1, input)
    }

    fmt.Println("tell me three family members you like.")
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        fmt.Print("family_member: ")
        fmt.Scanf("%s", &input)
        list2 = append(list2, input)
    }

    list := concat(list1, list2)

    for i := 0; i < 12; i++ {
        fmt.Println(list[i])
    }
}

func concat(a []string, b []string) []string {
    var list  []string
    list = make([]string, 6)
    list = append(list, a...)
    list = append(list, b...)
    return list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = make([]string, 3)
list2 = make([]string, 3)
```

I tought this would create a slice with a max of 3 indexes. But it creates two slices with 3 empty indexes. When using append() later on happens it appends it to the 4th index. (making the slice max of the slice 4 indexes, this kinda blew my mind as I tought the slice had a max of 3 indexes. So the above two lines need to be changed to:

```
list1 = make([]string, 0)
list2 = make([]string, 0)
```

This way there are not empty indexes anymore.